# Greenboard behind acrylic panel in shower

Tags: bathroom, drywall, shower, waterproofing

I've been reading a bit about bathroom drywall options, and have seen that "greenboard" water-resistant drywall is not recommended for use in the shower/tub wet areas for tile backing. Does that hold true regardless of what material is installed on top? We are having floor-to-ceiling acrylic panels installed for the shower. It seems these would be less water permeable in the long term, since there's no grout to deteriorate and allow water to seep through. But is it acceptable/up to code to install these acrylic panels on top of greenboard? Location is NJ, USA.

Comment: In my opinion green board is practically never appropriate in the tub/shower area. It could go above sinks, but in water assemblies I'd prefer cementitious boards nearly every time.

Comment: I do not like green board in shower surrounds or tub enclosures but it is ok to use in your application, I have found 20-30 year old homes that needed the tile in these areas redone because water finally made it through. The acrylic will only have a possibility of leaking at the seams.